# Mail is not going in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to sending mail but in that value is not going . Please help me how i can send values also . 
Controller part -

```
@c1=IssueTrackerGroup.where(id:@issue_request.issue_tracker_group_id).pluck(:id)

@c2 = IssueTrackerMember.where(issue_tracker_group_id: @c1).pluck(:employee_id)

        @emp = Employee.where(id: @c2)
        @emp.each do |s|
        IssueRequestMailer.issue_tracker_group_email(s.email).deliver_now
        end
```

mailer part -

```
def issue_tracker_group_email(s)
 s=s
 mail(to: s, subject: 'Support Request') 
 end
```

parameters which i want to pass -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>

 <h4>Support Request</h4>
    <p>
      This is to inform you that you have a support Request .
      Details are given below.<br><br>

<b>1. Support Master</b> - <%= @issue_request.try(:issue_master).try(:name) %><br><br>

      <b>2. Support Group</b> - <%= @issue_request.try(:issue_tracker_group).try(:name) %><br><br>

      <b>3. Support Priority</b> - <%= @issue_request.try(:issue_priority) %><br><br>

      <b>4. Description</b> - <%= @issue_request.try(:description) %><br><br>
        With Regards,<br><br>
        HR
     </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but how because mail is going . If i write c1 and c2 in issue_tracker_group_mail then it is showing an error .

Comment: what is meaning `mail is going`?

Comment: Use instance variables in `issue_tracker_group_email` method to share data to the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the variables `@issue_request`, `@c1` and `@c2` to the `issue_tracker_group_email` method.

```
IssueRequestMailer.issue_tracker_group_email(s.email, @issue_request, @c1, @c2).deliver_now
```

And then declare instance variables in `issue_tracker_group_email` method to share data to the view. (I assuming the instance variables you need in the view.)

```
def issue_tracker_group_email(mail_id, request, c1, c2)
  @issue_request = request
  @c1 = c1
  @c2 = c2
  mail(to: mail_id, subject: 'Support Request') 
end
```

Now, you can use `@issue_request`, `@c1` and `@c2` in your view.

P.S. Use meaningful variable names.

Hope this helps!